# gnuplot: unrecognized terminal option

Tags: pdf-generation, gnuplot

Can anyone tell me why I get the "unrecognized terminal option" when having

> set output "out.pdf"

Is there any package that I need to install for gnuplot 4.4?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Have you set the terminal?  The command

```
print GPVAL_TERMINALS
```

in gnuplot will list all the avialable terminals; if pdfcairo is in the list you should be good to go.  In general before setting the output you need to set the terminal, e.g.

```
set terminal pdf
set output 'out.pdf'
```

Comment: Yes! I set the terminal, to pdf not to pdfcairo. I changed it pdfcairo (set terminal pdfcairo enhanced monochrome ...) Still the same error!

Comment: Hmm.  Could you post the script you are using (or a minimal version)?  Also the output of `print GPVAL_COMPILE_OPTIONS` and `print GPVAL_TERMINALS` would be helpful.

Comment: I think just one the settings is incorrect. because I can run the script with `set terminal pdf`, but I have problem when running `set terminal pdf  monochrome solid fname 'Helvetica' fsize 14 size 16cm,12cm`

Comment: Got it.  Try `set terminal pdf monochrome solid font 'Helvetica,14' size 16cm,12cm`.  `fname` and `fsize` are not legitimate gnuplot options.  You set the font size within the font specification; it's not a separate option.  For more info you can type `help set terminal pdf`.

Comment: I can't find generated file, where is gnuplot saving it?

Comment: @shurrok if you are getting the 'unrecognized terminal option' error, gnuplot is probably not producing any file. If looking around this page and other gnuplot questions doesn't clarify things for you, it may be good to ask another question.

Answer (score 9):

Well, I had the same problem. I fixed this as follows using `home-brew`.

a) First to check what options are available with `gnuplot`

```
brew options gnuplot
```

This will produce something like :

```
--with-aquaterm
    Build with AquaTerm support
--with-cairo
    Build the Cairo based terminals
--with-libcerf
    Build with libcerf support
--with-pdflib-lite
    Build with pdflib-lite support
--with-qt@5.7
    Build with qt@5.7 support
--with-test
    Verify the build with make check
--with-wxmac
    Build wxmac support. Need with-cairo to build wxt terminal
--with-x11
    Build with x11 support
--without-gd
    Build without gd based terminals
--without-lua
    Build without the lua/TikZ terminal
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

b) uninstall gnuplot

```
brew uninstall gnuplot
```

c) reinstall with option cairo

```
brew install gnuplot --with-cairo
```

That's it. Afterwards, just set the terminal and provide output file. It worked for me.

```
set term pdf
set output 'myFile.pdf'
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way is using the pipe gnuplot capability. For example with `ps2pdf`:

```
set term postscript eps enhanced color 
set output '|ps2pdf - outputfile.pdf'
```

or with `gs` directly:

```
set output '|gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=outputfile.pdf -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE  -f -'
```

where the symbol `-` means the piped input file

Comment: When piping to ps2pdf my figure ended up being the wrong orientation in Latex, I assume this is because ps2pdf tries to be smart about guessing the correct orientation and could be fixed with a `-dAutoRotatePages` flag. I ended up using the pdf terminal instead because it worked out of the box.